# sql: show all rows just with different number

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables. Lets say one for actors where data the column is actorid and each row has values like 101, 102, 103, 104.

Now I have another table named work. It counts how many times a user worked on something. its name is workactor and it has two columns, actorid and typeofwork.

Now I want to create a query that counts how many different items of work each user did. I have been able to do that using the following query:

```
SELECT actors.actorid, COUNT(*) AS total
FROM workactor 
LEFT OUTER JOIN actors ON workactor.actorid=actors.actorid
GROUP BY workactor.actorid;
```

Now although this does count each type of work for every actor, it doesn't show 0 for any actor who is there in actors table but not in workactor table. I don't know what the issue is.

Comment: MySQL <> SQL Server - please correct your tags. And please format your query... no one can read a complex query in one line! And post your actual query `WHERE GROUP BY` is not valid syntax. And to solve you problem just reverse your tables, select from actors, join on workactor.

Comment: @DaleK sorry about that. I reformatted the question. Please have a look and let me know! thanks

Comment: I did let you know... the answer is the last part of my comment. I highly recommend using table aliases also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a `LEFT JOIN`, the first table is the one where you keep all rows.  In this case, you want all `actor`s.  So that goes first:

```
SELECT a.actorid, COUNT(wa.actor_id) AS total
FROM actors a LEFT JOIN
     workactor wa
     ON wa.actorid = a.actorid
GROUP BY a.actorid;
```

Note the other changes to the query:

- Table aliases make the query easier to write and to read.
- The `GROUP BY` is on `a.actorid`.  That is because `wa.actorid` could be `NULL`.
- The `COUNT()` is counting rows from the *second* table so it can return `0`.  In this context, `COUNT(*)` would never return `0`.